# what is the syntax to import function and object property in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am new in typescript (in Javascript also actually), I need to convert two lines of javascript syntax below into typescript

```
   const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
    const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn
```

I have tried to write like this, but it doesn't work:

```
import * as gcs() from '@google-cloud/storage'
import * as spawn.spawn from 'child-process-promise'
```

Comment: The second one should probably be `import { spawn } from 'child-process-promise'`

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in es6. You have to write:

```
import * as gcs from '@google-cloud/storage'
const something = gcs();
```

Comment: It would be weird though for a namespace object to be callable. Maybe it works with transpilers and legacy (commonjs) modules, but I wouldn't count on that.

Comment: @Bergi well based on the question description **gcs** is callable i think